# How can I setup a win 7 PC as a router?

Tags: windows-7, router, routing

I have an industrial PC with 4 Ethernet port, I would like to use this PC as a router on windows 7. Before we used Ubuntu so there is an open source solutiosn, but unfortunately the UPS power supply doesn't support Ubuntu, so now we have to change the operation system to windows embedded standard 7. Is it possible to set up a PC to act as a router.

Comment: Could you provide more detail on the network setup?

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution as the Zentyal on Ubuntu. Are there any?

Comment: That's not what Dave has asked.

Comment: I would like to use this PC as a firewall, but also I would like to use a remote desktop viewer to connect to the other computers, which are behind this PC.

Comment: We need the info on the network setup.  Are the other computers on the same network? Do you need the other devices on a different network?  More detail will give a better answer

Comment: The devices will be in an other subnet.

Comment: @KicsiMano please add new information to your original question by using the edit feature.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To forward packets (act as a router) between attached networks you can change/create a registry setting:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters

Value Name: IpEnableRouter
Value Type: REG_DWORD
Value Data: 1
```

To modify the static routing table use the `route` command.

To check it has been enabled use `ipconfig /all` and there should be a line:

```
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
```

Ref: [Microsoft Support article: Enabling IP Routing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99686)

Answer (score 1):

If all devices are connected to a NIC on the industrial PC, you would simply need to connect to the PC using Remote Desktop.  You can then connect to the other devices.

We use Dameware or VNC to make the conenction to the Industrial PC and the open an RDP conenction to the other connected PCs.   In some cases it is only needed to manage controls software on the Industrial PC for assoiated devices like cameras or PLCs.

You do not need to configure much, especially if you connect to the other subnets by IP.