# Connect to PC's behind other PC

Tags: networking

I have an industrial PC(with 4 Ethernet port)  with a static IP. There are connected  3 other PC to this industrial PC. Using ssh I can reach the industrial PC, how can I reach the PC's behind the industrial PC?

```
mylaptop->intenet->industria PC->PC1
                               ->PC2
                               ->PC3
                               ->PC4
```

**EDITED**

---

The PC1 PC2 PC3 and PC4 is in a  different subnet.

For example the IP of the industrial PC is: 134.102.23.XXX and the IP of the PCX is 198.162.0.xxx

Comment: what os is the industrial PC running?

Comment: it windows embedded standard 7. I installed freesshd

Comment: And can you reach the other PCs somehow from the industrial PC? What protocol? What kind of networking? What kind of IP addresses? What exactly are you trying to do? Details help hugely!

Comment: If you can `ssh` to the industrial PC, why can't you also `ssh` out from it?

Comment: This seems to be a variant of http://superuser.com/questions/394505/how-can-i-setup-a-win-7-pc-as-a-router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can ssh to the intermediate computer then you should be able to ssh further into the other computers (think of it as steps). If you don't want to do anything on the intermediate computer (only use it for getting through the firewall) then you can skip the creation of a shell on in by using the `-t` parameter of ssh:

```
ssh user@internet-facing-computer.com -t ssh user@computer1.local.network
```

This command will ask for the two passwords (if using password based authentication) on the two computers each time you are establishing the connection.

If you have to log in to the other computers more frequently then you could establish local port forwarding:

```
ssh user@internet-facing-computer.com -N -L 3333:192.168.1.1:22
```

This establishes a port forwarding from your local laptop port 3333 to port 22 on the computer on the local network at 192.168.1.1. You have to use the ip address because you don't have access to the local DNS.

In a new terminal window you can connect now to the computer behind the firewall:

```
ssh user@localhost -p 3333
```

You can use this approach to establish local port forwarding to each of the firewalled computers. Be sure to use different local ports for each of them (e.g. 3334, 3335).

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to the industrial PC you can connect to the others easily as noted in the reply to question [How can I setup a win 7 PC as a router?](https://superuser.com/questions/394505/how-can-i-setup-a-win-7-pc-as-a-router)

There are a number of tools that will aloow this.  Hwowever, more info is needed.  What is running OS on the other systems?  Do you have Admin access to all PCs?  Can you install software if required?  What are you trying to do on the other systems and do you need to act as the console user on each PC?

Comment: On the industrial PC is windows embedded 7, on the other PC are installed Windows 7. I have admin rights.On the other PC are running some software written in labview, so I need graphical interaction.

Comment: If you connect to the Industrial PC, you should be able to use RDP or something like VNC or Dameware (and others) to connect.  You should require no other setup around routing as the PC is connected to all subnets.  You may need to make firewall changes on all to obtain needed function

Answer (score 0):

You can setup port forwarding.

Also software like [Logmein](https://secure.logmein.com/)