# Windows 7 setup routing between 2 networks

Tags: windows-7, routing, ip

Situation:

```
               | access point | wi-fi     |   my machine |           | 2-nd machine |
               |  192.168.1.1 | --------- | 192.168.1.37 | Ethernet  |              |
Internet ----  | 76.77.15.87  |           |  192.168.0.1 | --------- | 192.168.0.2  |
```

I have 2 computers:

The 1-st is connected to the Internet through wi-fi interface. Network: 192.168.1.0/24 default gateway: 192.168.1.1 (IP of the wi-fi access point). It works.

Now I have another machine, connected to mine through the Ethernet interface. Here I have a second network with 2 machines: 192.168.0.0/24:

1. mine 192.168.0.1
2. other machine: 192.168.0.2 default gateway 192.168.0.1

ping between the machines works. ping google.com on the 2-nd machine doesn't work.

Now I need to setup the route between the internal and external networks on my machine.

I don't know, what default gateway should I setup on 192.168.0.1 machine for 192.168.0.0 network, because my machine is the default gateway for this network. I tried

```
route add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
```

but it doesn't work.

```
IPv4 routing table
===========================================================================
Active routes:
Network address       Network mask     Default gateway     Interface  Metrics
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.0.1    276
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.37     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.1.37      192.168.0.1    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.0.1    276
      192.168.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.1    276
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.1    276
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.37    281
     192.168.1.37  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.37    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.37    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.0.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.37    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.37    281
===========================================================================
```

Comment: I suspect you need this: http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `route` statement isn't what you want. The 192.168.1.1 router isn't the gateway for the 192.168.0.0/24 network (which is what your route statement says-- it's flat wrong).

You'll want to place a route on the 192.168.1.1 wireless router to give it a route to the 192.168.0.0/24 network via the 192.168.1.37 PC.

You'll also need to [enable IP routing on the Windows 7 PC](https://superuser.com/a/394564) to get it to forward packets.

Comment: I enabled IP routing and rebooted the machine. Also I set 192.168.1.37 as a default gateway for 192.168.0.1 interface. But it still doesn't work. I added the current routing table to my question.

Comment: ok I solved it by adding a route 192.168.0.0/24 to 192.168.1.37 on the access point, only now understood what you meant

Comment: So exactly what was the command you ended up using?

Answer (score 0):

You must share wireless connection in your machine and set dns in 2nd machine as: 192.168.0.1

then try to ping as follows:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.1.37
192.168.1.1
```

then ping the ip you obtained from pinging www.google.com at your machine in the 2nd machine.
if you set dns correctly you must get reply in all pings.

Comment: Sharing the connection is what the original poster is trying to do. Just not via ICS but with a manual, much more controlled setup.