# Windows 7 tcp/ip tunneling

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, routing, subnet

I have two networks connected to my windows 7 PC:

- 192.168.9.0/24 - wireless network with internet access
- 192.168.23.0/24 - my private network

wifi card IP: 192.168.9.23; my private network IP: 192.168.23.2

I'd like to set up tunneling both ways between these networks on my windows 7 machine.
I've already seen [Windows 7 setup routing between 2 networks](https://superuser.com/questions/777903/windows-7-setup-routing-between-2-networks#777904) and [How can I setup a win 7 PC as a router?](https://superuser.com/questions/394505/how-can-i-setup-a-win-7-pc-as-a-router/394564#394564)

```
C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig /all

Konfiguracja IP systemu Windows

   Nazwa hosta . . . . . . . . . . . : Amamiya
   Sufiks podstawowej domeny DNS . . :
   Typ węzła . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrydowy
   Routing IP włączony . . . . . . . : Tak
   Serwer WINS Proxy włączony. . . . : Nie
```

(sorry, it's in Polish, since windows seems to not understand people would like to have a choice of the language... anyway, it says "IP Routing enabled: Yes")

my routing table (excluding broadcast/multicast/localhost for clarity):

```
      192.168.9.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.9.23    279
     192.168.9.23  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.9.23    279
    192.168.9.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.9.23    279
     192.168.23.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.23.2     21
     192.168.23.2  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.23.2    276
   192.168.23.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.23.2    276
```

from the windows PC everything works well - I can access correctly both the internet and my private network. Now I'd like to be able to route between these two subnets (through my windows PC) but it doesn't seem to work.

Tried pinging 192.168.9.1 (wireless router) both from the windows machine, and my private subnet. From the windows machine it works, but pinging from private subnet, while correctly forwarding the ping to my windows machine (verified it using wireshark), doesn't get any replies.

Am I missing something in the setup? Is there any firewall setting that blocks forwarding traffic between the subnets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, since i was able to find out what was wrong.

Network layout:

```
192.168.23.0/24                                  192.168.9.0/24
-----------------------                          ------------------------
192.168.23.5 (server)
192.168.23.1 (router)
192.168.23.2            (----- windows -----)    192.168.9.23
                                                 192.168.9.1 (floor router)
```

There were two problems, neither of them on the windows side (and one another on the windows side, but unrelated to routing):

1. Windows was correctly tunneling the messages, but floor router didn't know where to send replies. After adding static route to 192.168.23.0/24 through my windows PC i was able to reach 192.168.9.0/24 from inside my subnet.
2. For some reason when accessing the server from outside my subnet replies from the server were getting lost (unless the server accessed directly the IP which sent the request). Forwarding was set on the router, but it didn't answer 'Redirect Host' when server was sending replies, so unless server had cached correct route already replies were lost.
   I had to move routing 192.168.23.0/24 -> 192.168.9.0/24 from the router configuration directly to the linux server. After `route add -net 192.168.9.0/24 gw 192.168.23.2` directly on server everything started working correctly.

As for why I didn't notice at first windows is correctly forwarding packets it's because I didn't notice I'm listening on only one network device in wireshark...

the third problem (the windows-related one, but not routing one) was that first thing after I managed to set up everything correctly was BSOD 0x000000D1 in the network card driver... Updated the driver, and for now everything works fine.