# ping a VPN IP of a connected device's IP

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ping, gopro

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I have a laptop which is connected to a GoPro Hero 3+ via Wifi.  I've also connected the laptop to a NETGEAR router via Ethernet cable.

I can ping the GoPro's VPN IP from the laptop (via wireless and access point):

```
ping 10.5.5.9
```

I can also ping the laptop from my computer (via router and Ethernet cable):

```
ping 192.168.1.11
```

However, can I can't ping the GoPro's VPN IP from the computer.  Is there a way I can do this?  Is there a way I can route from the computer to the laptop to the GoPro?  I'm sorry if this is an obvious question.  I'm pretty new to networking.

Sidenote:  In the long run, I want to be able to do the same thing except replace the laptop with a Wifi USB Adapter.  Also, [this site](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=920602&sid=2ad4fdde14c3f797283bf7e24a3a3ac9) suggests using a secondary router, but I don't have access to one as of now.

Just some IP stuff from the laptop:

```
C:\Users\local_admin>ipconfig

*snip*

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9167:9a6b:6d67:4c3e%19
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.11
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2c25:2b69:2890:bf71%18
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.5.5.108
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.5.5.9

*snip*

C:\Users\local_admin>route print

*snip*

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.11     20
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.5.5.9       10.5.5.108     25
         10.5.5.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.5.5.108    281
       10.5.5.108  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.5.5.108    281
       10.5.5.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.5.5.108    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.11    276
     192.168.1.11  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.11    276
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.11    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.11    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.5.5.108    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.11    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.5.5.108    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

*snip*

C:\Users\local_admin>
```

**UPDATE:**  I ended up using a Wifi USB Adaptor (IEEE 802.11 n WLAN).  It came with a software which allowed me to connect to the GoPro.  The Wifi USB Adaptor is connected to the desktop.  I can ping the VPN IP fine.  I won't post this as the answer because I still want to know if I can do it via laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a bridge connections between the two networks (Wifi and Ethernet). Select both the network adapters from the Network Properties window (Run > ncpa.cpl) and choose "Add to Bridge".

In general, a network bridge is software or hardware that connects two or more networks so that they can communicate.

On your case, it has to contact to VPN network. So, give a try by bridging the network and see the outcome.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see "Add to Bridge".  I do see "Bridge Connections" after right clicking.  However, when I click that, I get an error: "To create a Network Bridge, you must select at least two LAN or High-Speed Internet connections that are not being used by Internet Connection Sharing".

Comment: The option differs by OS. Select two network adapters (Wifi and Ethernet) at the same time and choose "Bridge Connections" after right clicking it.

Comment: That allowed me to bridge.  I'm using Windows 7 on the laptop.  It completed a loading bar, but nothing else happened.  I still can't `ping` the VPN IP from the desktop though.

Comment: Actually, now I can't `ping` the laptop from desktop.  And I can't `ping` the GoPro from the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two different networks, a bridge is not the solution, because it doesn't work on network layer. You need your laptop works as a router. May be this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/394505/how-can-i-setup-a-win-7-pc-as-a-router) helps you.

Comment: Update: direct to the [source](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/99686)

Comment: I tried Values `0` and `1` for `IPEnableRouter` on the laptop.  I added the route: `route add 10.5.5.9 192.168.1.11` on the laptop.  However, I still couldn't ping `10.5.5.9` from the desktop.

Comment: what are the IPs on your laptop?

Comment: Just updated the opening post with that info

Comment: I think you need to clear your route table and apply this `route add 10.5.5.9 IF 4` and `route add 192.168.1.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 IF 2`

Comment: Would it be wise to clear the route table?  Is there an easy way to back it up before clearing it?

Comment: Also, `route add 10.5.5.9 IF 4` this command doesn't work (even after clearing the table).  This `192.168.1.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 IF 2` doesn't work either.