# how to connect 2 lans with hosts having same ip?

Tags: networking, network-shares

am in a testing lab in my office with 6 different LANs having 3 PC each, let them be called machine1, machine 2 and machine 3 connected via a switch. And the softwares they are using only work with 3 definite IP addresses let's say x,y and z respectively.

So all 6 LANs having these 3 similar PC have exactly same manually configured IP addresses. Now I want to connect these 6 LANs to share files, folders and other test data.
HOW?
because I just can't connect to the same switch or router as that leads to IP conflicts.

So can someone help me out with this?

One solution i was thinking was to install a 2nd NIC/LAN card and create a 2nd network to get them on a network.

Anything else that might work?

Comment: Put a remapping device between each LAN and their common interconnect. So if they're both numbered in 192.168.10.0/24, put a device to remap one LAN to 192.168.1.0/24 and a second device to remap the other LAN to 192.168.2.0/24 in front of the other. Now, devices on each LAN can reach all devices on the other LAN on their remapped addresses.

Comment: I forgot to mention - networking is not my area of expertise.. am from a coding and testing background.. a little elaboration to your solution would be much appreciated.. can u name a remapping device? couldnt find anything about it. Thanks

Comment: If this is a testing lab, and you have the option to add a second network, why don't you have the option to change the addressing of the current setup so that the conflicts don't arise?  I am asking this to understand the scope of options.

Comment: the testing tools we are using work on a predefined ip addresses hard-coded into the software itself. using a second network would allow us to share files and data without interrupting the first network.     changing the addressing means changing ip address of 1500+ test cases in all the machines.

Comment: While this [answer](http://superuser.com/a/1072188/238539) does solve the problem for you, I would instead fix the root of the problem. Why on Earth the software can not be reprogrammed to eliminate the hardcoded IP-addresses? This setup will keep creating problems for you in the future. A very simple task (sharing files) became a nightmare just because someone was lazy and hardcoded the network settings.

Comment: "One solution i was thinking was to install a 2nd NIC/LAN card and create a 2nd network to get them on a network" -- yes, but you may have troubles if you don't disable the addresses on the first network.  Machine names (e.g., DNS/etc.) may point to the duplicated IP addresses.  When machines share their names, looking up the names may result in communication via IP address to the wrong machine.  The approach you said can work, but there can also be problems if you're not careful.  (NAT may take more setup, but may also be more prone to avoid the particular issue I'm mentioning.)

Comment: I have tried this setup with 3 lans i.e around 12-15 PCs.. no such issues yet

Answer (score 4):

If you have a router for each of your lans and maybe an additional switch, you can build your own small "internet" on a dedicated `lan0` network. These methods will also work with more than 2 lans:

[image]

This setup could be accomplished even using basic home grade routers, as they are normally already configured for **NAT** (Network Address Translation) and masquerade the outgoing traffic on the `wan` port.
(This means: The routers hide the addresses of the machines in `lan1` and `lan2`, by replacing the source address in all packets with their own `wan` IP)

When you use static IP addresses in your `lan1` and `lan2` networks, you have to manually set a **default route** on your machines pointing to their upstream router IP (`eth1`)

When you use static IP addresses on the `wan` ports of your routers, you should use **SNAT** instead of **MASQUERADE** (as typically used when using DHCP to configure the `wan` port).

Optional: Add a router to `lan0` and configure as **DHCP server**, to give IPs dynamically to the `wan` ports of the routers.

### Option 1 Using DNAT (port forwarding):

Now you can configure some port forwarding rules on your routers.
Depending on what services you want to share, this could get a bit complicated.
For example to be able to have access via SSH from `lan1` to `lan2` and vice versa, you would need some rules like this (when using linux router with iptables):

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 2202 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.2:22
iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 2203 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.3:22
iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 2204 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.4:22
```

Where you could access an individual ssh server using the forwarded ports from the other lan. For example `lan1 10.0.0.2` can access `lan2 10.0.0.3` with IP and port combination `10.1.0.2:2203`.

### Option 2 Using VPN network:

[image]

If you have another machine available (called `server1`), place it on the `lan0` network and configure it as a VPN server. For example when using [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html) a new virtual interface called `tun0` is used for the VPN network.

Install a VPN client on all your machines and connect them all to the VPN server via IP `10.1.0.100`, This will not require any port forwarding on the routers, just masquerading or SNAT.

Again, with the example of VPN, this will create an additional virtual interface `tun0` on each of your clients, where you can assign each one a **unique IP address** on the VPN subnet `10.8.0.0/24` where they can communicate to each other (In OpenVPN you need to use the directive `client-to-client` to allow this).

This subnet is also called a "VPN tunnel".

**Alternative 1 without dedicated routers:**

As you suggested, you can install an **additional NIC** in one of your machines in each of your lans and configure it as a router, replacing the dedicated routers in the above images.

**Alternative 2 without dedicated VPN server:**

You can use one of your machines in `lan1` and `lan2` to host the **VPN server** and access it from the other lans over a forwarded port as described in option 1.

### Option 3 Using a VPN for your test IPs

Depending on what you test, this might be the simplest solution, as it requires no hardware at all, except for a switch.

**Disadvantage:** This will have a performance impact on the test network, as the VPN tunnel adds another layer of complexity to all the network packets. You can minimize the effect by disabling encryption, for example add the following directives to an OpenVPN config:

```
auth none
cipher none
```

Network Setup as follows:

```
lan0 10.0.0.0/24
+-----+------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+----+
      |            |            |             |            |            |
      |            |            |             |            |            |
  eth0|        eth0|        eth0|         eth0|        eth0|        eth0|
+----------+ +----------+ +----------+  +----------+ +----------+ +----------+
|10.0.0.1  | |10.0.0.2  | |10.0.0.3  |  |10.0.0.4  | |10.0.0.5  | |10.0.0.6  |
|machine1  | |machine2  | |machine3  |  |machine1  | |machine2  | |machine3  |
|lan1      | |lan1      | |lan1      |  |lan2      | |lan2      | |lan2      |
|VPN-server| |VPN-client| |VPN-client|  |VPN-server| |VPN-client| |VPN-client|
|10.8.0.x  | |10.8.0.y  | |10.8.0.z  |  |10.8.0.x  | |10.8.0.y  | |10.8.0.z  |
+----------+ +----------+ +----------+  +----------+ +----------+ +----------+
  tun0|        tun0|        tun0|         tun0|        tun0|        tun0|
      |            |            |             |            |            |
      |            |            |             |            |            |
+-----+------------+------------+----+  +-----+------------+------------+----+
lan1 (VPN) 10.8.0.0/24                  lan2 (VPN) 10.8.0.0/24
```

You just need to adjust the subnet of the VPN to the subnet and IPs `x, y, z` you need for your tests.

Comment: hey man, thanx. option 1 looks great but we do have more than 8-10 lans and buying a dedicated router wont be much efficient.  You did mention to use NIC as a router, but how exactly? any help on that too?

Comment: and sorry I forgot to mention, these systems are Windows only PC, LINUX wont work.   Let's suppose we get Option 1 to setup and work(assuming it does with windows), how will a PC from lan1 will interact with pc from another lan.. what you described - "For example `lan1 10.0.0.2` can access `lan2 10.0.0.3` with IP and port combination `10.1.0.2:2203`"  works great for 2 lans.. how can I interact with the 3rd or an other LAN? Apologies if sounds ridiculous.. but as I said networking's not my domain.

Comment: In Windows this is called ICS (Internet Connection Sharing), the equivalent to masquerading in Linux. You need to enable IP forwarding see http://superuser.com/a/394564. Port fowarding, to my knowledge, is only possible with Windows Server version or with a tool like this one: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pjs-passport/. But first please clarify, why is Option 3 no solution? It does not need any router or additional NICs. For your second comment: The next (`lan3`) would have a `wan` IP of `10.1.0.3` on the router and it works. What about installing an usb wireless adapter on all machined?

Comment: I didn't mean opt.2/3 ain't a solution.just that op.1 sounded a bit better.Due to some stupid company policy we cannot use any opensource only licensed products.Coming to use of wireless adapters- I just used 6 lans with 3 pc as an example,in realtiy we have around `15 lans` with `3-7 pc` each i.e around `90 PCs` and its not really economically viable.We are looking for workarounds with available equipments.And apology for my 2nd comment how'll they interact.. it was just an error in my understanding of the statement. It should and will work if I can get it to work with windows 7.Thanks a lot.

Comment: You would thank me the most by accepting my answer. Your question is very broad and does not mention anything about the hardware or software requirements mentioned here. All the 3 options should be possible to solve the problem in your question, it is up to you what hardware or software you use to accomplish it. Please create a new question where you specify in detail what hardware and software you have (also real lan sizes) and what your requirements are in regard to hardware, software and corporate policies. Also please clarify what "licensed products" mean. As OpenVPN is licensed under GPL.

Comment: Am looking into as how I can implement option 1.  Licensed here refers to as in 'paid + after purchase support'. I don't think it requires a new post now. your solution would help. My apologies for the incomplete representation of the facts. have recently joined this office and found myself fumbling around the restrictions and policies only after I had offered the solution.   any further help with how to get it up and running would be really helpful. I might be able to get them to install pjs passport as there are no paid alternatives.

Comment: I am sure you should be able to find suitable commercial products for all options, but certainly a ton of commercial VPN products exist (I would really consider option 3, if at all possible, as it is simpler). I do not have any experience with it and also not with configuring Windows as router. One thing to consider is to use a Windows Server version instead of Windows 7 (shouldn't conflict with your policies), it will allow you to configure machines as routers. Or you try it with Windows 7 and a combination of `ICS` and `netsh` as described here: http://woshub.com/port-forwarding-in-windows/.

Comment: okay. will try the VPN one. I just hope it doesn't lead to any issues with the setup. I dont know if the crappy testing tools we are using will raise any issues with the use of vpn or not. Let's hope for the best.

Comment: What protocols are used by your test setup? You can check if it is TCP/IP based with cmd > `netstat -ano`. If you need protocols which are not based on IP, you need to use a **bridged VPN** instead of a normal **routed VPN**. This will use Ethernet bridging and simulate an Ethernet network, like the machines would have been connected physically to a switch/hub with Ethernet cables. This will add again more overhead to the network communication in contrast to routed VPNs. If you're not sure how your test setup communicates, and performance isn't a problem, consider using bridged VPN to be safe.