# Windows-7 Routing: Wireless Network <-> OpenVPN Tap

Tags: windows-7, routing

My goals on Windows 7:

- For wireless connected users to be bridged or routed to the OpenVPN Tap network.
- For any console or RDC logged in user to have normal (not VPN) access to the internet.
- On system startup the headless and auto-start of all components.

I can manually set the OpenVPN Tap adapter to share with Wireless Network 3 (MS Virtual Wifi Miniport) but the share is not persistent - after reboot another manual share setting is required. There is no W7 patch to fix this.

The wireless hosted network was created with:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow "ssid=MySSID" "key=MyKey" keyUsage=persistent 
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

The second netsh is not persistent – after reboot the hosted network is not started. I can fix that in the script that starts the VPN.

On SuperUser I found “[How can I setup a win 7 PC as a router?](https://superuser.com/questions/394505/how-can-i-setup-a-win-7-pc-as-a-router)”.

From postings at SuperUser on routing between two NICs it seems two routes are required. I’m still confused on how to construct the two routes. I also have the requirement for console and RDC users have non-VPN internet access. And all this on the one NIC, I hope.

For reference here is info on the interfaces and routes:

```
Hosted network settings 
----------------------- 
    Mode                   : Allowed
    SSID name              : "MySSID"
    Max number of clients  : 10
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP

Hosted network status   
--------------------- 
    Status                 : Started
    BSSID                  : 98:48:27:66:28:d5
    Radio type             : 802.11n
    Channel                : 10
    Number of clients      : 0

Configuration for interface "Wireless Network Connection 3"     MS Virtual Wifi Miniport
    DHCP enabled:                         No
    InterfaceMetric:                      10
    Statically Configured DNS Servers:    103.86.96.100
                                          103.86.99.100
    Register with which suffix:           Primary only
    Statically Configured WINS Servers:   None

Configuration for interface "Wireless Network Connection 2"     TP-Link Wireless USB
    DHCP enabled:                         Yes
    InterfaceMetric:                      5
    DNS servers configured through DHCP:  None
    Register with which suffix:           Primary only
    WINS servers configured through DHCP: None

Configuration for interface "OpenVPN TAP-Windows6"
    DHCP enabled:                         Yes
    InterfaceMetric:                      10
    DNS servers configured through DHCP:  103.86.96.100
                                          103.86.99.100
    Register with which suffix:           Primary only
    WINS servers configured through DHCP: None

Configuration for interface "OpenVPN Wintun"
    DHCP enabled:                         No
    InterfaceMetric:                      5
    Statically Configured DNS Servers:    None
    Register with which suffix:           Primary only
    Statically Configured WINS Servers:   None

Configuration for interface "Local Area Connection"
    DHCP enabled:                         Yes
    IP Address:                           192.168.0.112
    Subnet Prefix:                        192.168.0.0/24 (mask 255.255.255.0)
    Default Gateway:                      192.168.0.1
    Gateway Metric:                       20
    InterfaceMetric:                      20
    DNS servers configured through DHCP:  192.168.0.1
    Register with which suffix:           Primary only
    WINS servers configured through DHCP: None

Configuration for interface "Local Area Connection 2"     Not Used
    DHCP enabled:                         Yes
    InterfaceMetric:                      5
    Register with which suffix:           Primary only
    WINS servers configured through DHCP: None

Configuration for interface "Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1"
    DHCP enabled:                         No
    IP Address:                           127.0.0.1
    Subnet Prefix:                        127.0.0.0/8 (mask 255.0.0.0)
    InterfaceMetric:                      50
    Statically Configured DNS Servers:    None
    Register with which suffix:           Primary only
    Statically Configured WINS Servers:   None

===========================================================================
Interface List
 23...34 e8 94 f8 85 94 ......TP-Link Gigabit PCI Express Adapter
 18...98 48 27 66 28 d5 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
 16...98 48 27 66 28 d5 ......TP-Link Wireless USB Adapter
 15...00 ff c6 01 bf 5f ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 14...........................Wintun Userspace Tunnel
 11...44 8a 5b 25 f8 05 ......Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 21...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.112     40
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.112    276
    192.168.0.112  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.112    276
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.112    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.112    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.112    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 11    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 11    266 fe80::d055:7ea9:674e:5cc7/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to go in a completely different direction.

But how to delete this posted question? I can't find any option.